# How to display numbers from contact list?

Tags: android

I use the code below to display contact numbers, but it is displaying names and numbers from the contact list.

```
public void getContacts(Context context){
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI));
}
```

Like the above code how can I use the below code for getting only contact numbers from the contact list? I need to display only contact numbers without showing names. Please help with the right solution to solve this problem.

```
Uri personUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, personId);
Uri phonesUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(personUri, People.Phones.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
String[] proj = new String[] {Phones._ID, Phones.TYPE, Phones.NUMBER, Phones.LABEL}
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(phonesUri, proj, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and look at this site:
[Query contacts](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/).

There are multiple methods for retrieving different content from contacts.

Hopefully that could help.